# Formatting breaklines using ICETOOL's DISPLAY

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I'm using DFSORT's ICETOOL DISPLAY operator to generate a list of accounts. I'm using a 'BREAK' on the branches to separate the accounts by sortcode and then sum the balance for the account. Everything works fine, but I get an additional entry(account) after summing the balance using BTOTAL. I've added my code below and the result so you better understand my question.

**code**

```
//SUR0007 JOB (5678),'ACCOUNTS'                          
//RUNIT EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                                 
//TOOLMSG DD SYSOUT=*                                    
//DFSMSG DD SYSOUT=*                                     
//TOOLIN DD *                                            
         DISPLAY FROM(INPUT2) LIST(REPORT) -                      
         TITLE('LIST OF BANK ACCOUNTS BY BRANCH')  -          
         HEADER('ACCOUNT') ON(2,8,BI,E'99999999') -               
         HEADER('BALANCE') ON(3,6,BI,E'99999999') -               
         HEADER('OWNER') ON(13,30,CH) -                           
         BTITLE('SORTCODE:') BREAK(1,4,BI,E'999999') -            
         BTOTAL('BRANCH TOTAL:') -                                
         TOTAL('GRAND TOTAL:')                                    
/*                                                       
//INPUT2 DD DSN=USER.CICS.Z022.BANK.ACCOUNTS,DISP=SHR
//REPORT DD SYSOUT=*
```

**result**

```
  SORTCODE:000012

  ACCOUNT    BALANCE  
 --------   --------  
 91317760   97999587  

 BRANCH TOTAL :        
 91317760   97999587
```

**Expected result**

```
 SORTCODE:000012

 ACCOUNT    BALANCE  
 --------   --------  
 91317760   97999587  

 BRANCH TOTAL : 97999587
```

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFSORT's ICETOOL DISPLAY operator has many options, which means there is extensive documentation for it.

You should consult the *DFSORT Getting Started* manual for introductory-level use, and *DFSORT Application Programming Guide* for more high-level use.

Within BCOUNT, all *numeric* fields will appear with totals. Your account is numeric (binary), but if you can't make it non-numeric you can use `NOST` (you can pretend that means NO Sub-Totals) as part of the formatting for any field that you do not want to be summed automatically.

To get your BTOTAL text to appear on the same line as the totals, use `STATLEFT` in the report description.

Here's an example of the use of both from the *Application Programming Guide*:

```
 DISPLAY FROM(ACCTS) LIST(FANCY) -
        TITLE('Accounts Report for First Quarter') -
        DATE(MD4/) BLANK -
        HEADER('Amount') ON(12,6,ZD,C1,N08) -
        HEADER(Id') ON(NUM,N02) -
        HEADER('Acct#') ON(31,3,PD,NOST,LZ) -
        HEADER('Date') ON(1,4,ZD,E'99/99',NOST) -
        INDENT(2) BETWEEN(5) -
        STATLEFT -
        TOTAL('Total for Q1') -
        AVERAGE('Average for Q1')
```

There is coding for a plain version of the same report:

```
DISPLAY FROM(ACCTS) LIST(PLAIN) -
    TITLE('Accounts Report for First Quarter') -
    DATE(MD4/) BLANK -
    HEADER('Amount') ON(12,6,ZD) -
    HEADER(Id') ON(NUM) -
    HEADER('Acct#') ON(31,3,PD) -
    HEADER('Date') ON(1,4,ZD) -
    TOTAL('Total for Q1') -
    AVERAGE('Average for Q1')
```

The output, with explanation from the example, is:

> This example shows some options you can use to improve the appearance
>   of a DISPLAY report. The first DISPLAY operator produces a "plain"
>   report, and the second DISPLAY operator uses the options shown in bold
>   to produce a "fancy" report.

```
The PLAIN output starts on a new page and looks as follows:

Accounts Report for First Quarter               05/04/2001

         Amount                 Id                  Acct#                    Date
---------------    ---------------    -------------------    --------------------
          93271                  1                  15932                     106
         137622                  2                    187                     128
          83147                  3                  15932                     212
         183261                  4                   2158                     217
          76389                  5                    187                     305
         920013                  6                  15932                     319

Total for Q1
        1493703                                     50328                    1287

Average for Q1
         248950                                      8388                     214



The FANCY output starts on a new page and looks as follows:

Accounts Report for First Quarter             05/04/2001

                       Amount         Id        Acct#      Date
                     --------        ---       ------     -----
                       932.71          1        15932     01/06
                     1,376.22          2        00187     01/28
                       831.47          3        15932     02/12
                     1,832.61          4        02158     02/17
                       763.89          5        00187     03/05
                     9,200.13          6        15932     03/19

Total for Q1        14,937.03

Average for Q1       2,489.50
```

> Here is an explanation of the extra options used for the "fancy"
>   report:
>
> ```
> First ON field: In the PLAIN report, BLANK causes ICETOOL to print
> ```
>
> the 6-byte ZD values as unedited digits with leading zeros suppressed.
>   But for this example, we know the digits really represent dollars and
>   cents. So in the FANCY report, we use the C1 formatting item (one of
>   thirty-three available masks) to print the values with a comma (,) as
>   the thousands separator and a period (.) as the decimal point.
>
> ```
> In the PLAIN report, TOTAL causes ICETOOL to allow 15 digits for the
> ```
>
> values because it does not know how many digits are needed. But
>   for this example, we know the total amount will not exceed 8 digits.
>   So in the FANCY report, we use the N08 formatting item to set the
>   number of digits to 8. This decreases the column width for the field.
>
> ```
> Second ON field: In the PLAIN report, NUM causes ICETOOL to allow 15
> ```
>
> digits for the record number because it does not know how many
>   digits are needed. But for this example, we know the number of records
>   will not exceed 99. So in the FANCY report, we use the N02 formatting
>   item to set the number of digits to 2. This decreases the column width
>   for the record number.
>
> ```
> Third ON field: In the PLAIN report, TOTAL and AVERAGE cause ICETOOL to
> ```
>
> print the total and average for this 3-byte PD field. But
>   for this example, we know we do not want statistics for the field
>   because it is an account number. So in the FANCY report, we use the
>   NOST formatting item to suppress the statistics for this field.
>
> ```
> In the PLAIN report, the default mask of A0 causes ICETOOL to suppress
> ```
>
> leading zeros for this 3-byte PD field. But for this example,
>   we know that we want to show leading zeros for the field because it is
>   an account number. So in the FANCY report, we use the LZ formatting
>   item to print leading zeros for this field.
>
> ```
> Fourth ON field: In the PLAIN report, BLANK causes ICETOOL to print the
> ```
>
> 4-byte ZD values as unedited digits with leading zeros
>   suppressed. But for this example, we know the digits represent a date
>   (month and day). So in the FANCY report, we use the E'99/99'
>   formatting item to print the values with leading zeros and a slash (⁄)
>   between the month and day.
>
> ```
> In the PLAIN report, TOTAL and AVERAGE cause ICETOOL to print the total
> ```
>
> and average for this 4-byte ZD field. But for this example, we
>   know we do not want the total or average for this field because it is
>   a date. So in the FANCY report, we use the NOST formatting item to
>   suppress the statistics for this field.
>
> ```
> Note: In some applications, we might want the minimum and maximum for a
> ```
>
> date displayed with E'pattern', so we would not specify NOST for
>   the date field.
>
> ```
> INDENT: In the PLAIN report, ICETOOL starts the report in column 2
> ```
>
> (after the control character), by default. But for this example, we
>   want to indent the report a bit. So in the FANCY report, we use the
>   INDENT(2) operand to indent the report by 2 blanks so it starts in
>   column 4.
>
> ```
> BETWEEN: In the PLAIN report, ICETOOL uses 3 blanks between the columns
> ```
>
> of data, by default. But for this example, we want more space
>   between the columns. So in the FANCY report, we use the BETWEEN(5)
>   operand to insert 5 blanks between the columns.
>
> ```
> STATLEFT: In the PLAIN report, ICETOOL prints the strings for TOTAL
> ```
>
> and AVERAGE under the first column of data, by default, and uses
>   two lines for each statistic to avoid having the string overlay the
>   value. But for this example, we would like to have the TOTAL and
>   AVERAGE strings stand out in the report and also have each string on
>   the same line as its value. So in the FANCY report, we use the
>   STATLEFT operand to print the TOTAL and AVERAGE strings to the left of
>   the first column of data.

Here's the link, which also includes a "plain" version of the report to contrast with the fancy one: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.icea100/ice2ca_Example_1110.htm

I located the link by search-engineing for `icetool display statleft nost`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. dont mean to be  noob but could give an example of both NOST and STATLEFT. i couldn't find anything on NOST.

Comment: Never mind :) figured it out. thanks man. once i added NOST to remove unwanted subtotals, the branch total was aligned with the subtotal i didn't have to use STATLEFT.